# How to reset the angular scope variable when the Html tag gets executed?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hy, I have a variable bound to my scope,

```
$scope.isSuccess = {
       invalidPhone : false
}
```

And I am using a span to display a message when the variable gets true ...

```
<form name = "myForm">
    <span ng-if="isSuccess.invalidPhone && myForm.$submitted">
          Please enter valid phone no.
    </span>
</form>
```

Now I am calling a Js method when the form gets submitted..which validates the phone number and set

```
$scope.isSuccess.invalidPhone = true
```

**Only if it is incorrect**.

Now I want to **reset the value of this variable to false** when my **span gets executed**. How to do it ? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean when you say "span gets executed"? What is executing the span?

Comment: @georgeawg actualy I am validating the phone number when the form gets submitted , so need to reset the variable every time after I've checked whether its value is true or not, and I am checking in my span tag using ng-if when I am displaying error message , So how to just change my variable value after this particular  span. Thanks

Comment: AngularJS is using two way data binding mechanism. You just need to reset the '$scope.isSuccess.invalidPhone' value then the span automatically will show or hide the content. You can reset the variable on successful validation of the data.

Comment: Yes I am changing its value if phone number is not correct using the method that called when form submitted but actually now after its value changed and I’ve checked now I need to reset its value , I can create a method in Js but how can I call within or just after my span , whether my msg displayed or not.. @Ganesh help Is there any angular directive that can be used to call my method... if I call two methods at same time when form submitted since there is only one button , then it will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ng-change` directive to update status of the flag:

```html
<form name = "myForm">
    <input name="phoneNumber" ng-model="data.num" type="text" 
           ng-change="updateStatus(data.num)" /> 
    <span ng-if="isSuccess.invalidPhone && myForm.$submitted">
          Please enter valid phone no.
    </span>
</form>
```

Every time the user changes the phone number, the function will be called:

```
$scope.updateStatus = function(num) {
    //Check phone number here
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms - Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)
- [AngularJS ngModel Controller API Reference - $validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators)
- [AngularJS ngModel Controller API Reference - $asyncValidators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators)